# Magento installation on live server is throwing error

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1.7

I am trying to install Magento 2 fresh copy on Live Server but it is throwing the below error

**What i did:**

- Downloaded Magento 2 latest CE version
- Uploaded to server root directory
- Unzip then
- Visit my website shop.site.com/setup
- And it throws the below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'databasemy.store_website' doesn't
>   exist in
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SE in
>   /var/www/vhosts/shop.site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 235

Comment: the code which is you used for installation is not  proper, Or your server does not  configure properly  for Magento2

Comment: Server is configured as per the requriements @AmitBera

Answer (score 1):

Set write permissions for web server's user for file **app/etc/env.php**.

It's must help.

Comment: This file doesn't exist in app/etc/ directory. I am installing a fresh copy.

Comment: please check the edit i posted wrong error. Thanks

Comment: Your database `databasemy` is empty? Can you check it?

Comment: yes it is empty i am installing magento via installer like site.com/setup

Comment: At what stage of wizard setup error is occur? Do you said proper database username in wizard setup with permissions for creating tables in database?

Comment: Actually my database is empty i have deleted all tables. And i extract magento 2 files in root directory and when i visit shop.site.com/Setup it throws the above error!

Comment: It's interesting, from where instalation took database's name. Do you have `app/etc/env.php` file?

Comment: No that files is also not present :)

Comment: I think magento generate that via Installer later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67101/discussion-between-evgeny-levinsky-and-iftikhar-uddin).

Answer (score 1):

please Try after change  permission of your magento application.

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;
chmod 777 ./app/etc;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**OR**

You can use following

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento; && && sudo chmod 755 app/etc;
```